# Find array's in another array value (Sentence)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am getting confused in a situation. I have a array list of words like 300 or more, and I have another array list of sentences like 500 or more. So now I want to extract the Sentences that matches with the words list. ex,

```
$a = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'one', 'three', 'five'];
$b = [
   'lorem ipsum dolor',
   'one word',
   'three horse',
   'ten dolor'
];
```

I want to extract the $b sentences based on $a words. I don't want to use foreach because it will be a n numbers of loop. What is the possible feasible way to solve this.

Comment: so first case is just e.g dolor is not matched with in first array so it is false right ?

Comment: actually part of matching is also need to be extracted

Comment: in your case `foreach` loop will be used with `strpos()` function

Comment: there will a lot of words and it will take a lot of time. I want to skip that times and want a result by a good alogorithm

Comment: @KapilPaul not possible.. you need `foreach` loop for multiple sentences  (500+ sentences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By invoking the magic of `preg_grep` and regular expressions.

```
$a = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'one', 'three', 'five'];

$pattern = '/\b('.implode('|',array_map(function($w){
      return preg_quote($w,'/'); //escape the delimiter too
 },$a)).')\b/i';

$b = [
   'lorem ipsum dolor',
   'one word',
   'three horse',
   'ten dolor'
];

print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $b));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lorem ipsum dolor
    [1] => one word
    [2] => three horse
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d09f346bf0d48ae2308b491f9ac06fac2a62b3c7)

If you are sure that "words" will not contain anything special to Regex (mostly punctuation), you can do it as simply as this:

```
function matchWordsInSentances($words, array $sentances){
   if(!is_array($words))$words = [$words];
   return preg_grep('/\b('.implode('|',$words).')\b/i', $sentances);
}
```

> **preg_grep** — Return array entries that match the pattern
>
> array **preg_grep** ( string **$pattern**, array **$input** [, int **$flags** = 0 ] )
>
> Returns the array consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

The array map + preg quote, is a safety feature, for your refrence:

> **preg_quote** — Quote regular expression characters
>    string **preg_quote** ( string **$str** [, string **$delimiter** = NULL ] )
>
> **preg_quote()** takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression characters are: **. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -**
>
> Note that **/** is not a special regular expression character.
>
> **delimiter** If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required by the PCRE functions. The **/** is the most commonly used delimiter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

You don't "have" to use them, and they do add an iteration over the array of "words" but if you can have things like `.` or `?` or even `*` in there you may want to use it.  Basically it escapes those things so they don't get interpreted as part of the Regex.  Of couses if you know Regex, you could always leave that out and take advantage of it like `$words = ["shoes?"]` which will match `shoe` and `shoes`.

**Regex explanation**

The pattern used is pretty strait forward:

- `\b` word boundary, spaces, punctuation, start and end of string
- `(...)` capture group
- `|` or  (`word` OR `word` etc.)
- `\i` case insensitive flag.

In this case the full pattern looks like this:

```
 /\b(lorem|ipsum|one|three|five)\b/i
```

Or in English, start at a word boundary, match any word in the list, end at the ending word boundary, match case insensitively.

Performance wise, who knows? When in doubt, benchmark them both and compare the time difference. The nice thing about `preg_quote` is we are collapsing one of the arrays, and then letting PHP and the PCRE (Regex engine) handle implementing the loops that are needed.

Enjoy.

Comment: OP said: "i have 500+ sentences and i don't want to used `foreach` loop". you used only 1 sentences for search..

Comment: `you used only 1 sentences` no I used 5 or the example provided, adding 95 or 295 more doesn't matter to the code.  Or in otherwords there are 5 sentences in `$b` and as I said to add, 10k more even, to that array is simply a matter of how you populate it.

Comment: Did you read the part about `preg_quote`.  Also your list of words may not be clean such as it could contain spaces etc...  I have no idea what could be in there.  Give me an example of one that doesn't match something it should, Id need the word and the sentence.

Comment: you are right. let me explore a more and I will let you know

Comment: Depending how you get the words you can use `$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array))` or some other way to remove emptiness.